# How Spark performs write operation to Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I am working in Spark and still new to it. I am working on a job that reads data from some source, do some transformations and write to Hive.

For writing to Hive, I am doing `dataframe.write.insertInto(hive_table)`

My question is how does Spark write the entire `dataframe` to Hive? Will it write in parallel like different partitions on different executors will be written in parallel or will it collect all the data from various partitions to driver and then try to insert in one go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark and Hive partitions are different. Spark executors will be writing in parallel to various Hive partitions.
Spark partitions will be processed in parallel by executors and when each executors encounters a Hive partition key, it will write to a new file in Hive location for that key.
So if you have 5 Spark partitions being processed in parallel and data in Hive is to be written in 3 partitions, whenever each executor will encounter a key for Hive partition, it will write to a file for that partitions.
You will see 5 files in each of the 3 Hive partition location written by each of the executors

Comment: I don't have any partitions in the Hive table. As per your comment, I think I got the answer - data is written to Hive in parallel. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, written in parallel